# javascript sorting array of objects by date

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes an array of objects and I need to sort the array by day; it looks like this:

```
function Myfunction (TheDays) {

  var TheDaysToSort = $.extend(false, TheDays);

  function SortOrder (a, b) {
     var Day1 = a['TheDate'];
     var Day2 = b['TheDate'];
     return Day1 - Day2;
  };

  TheDaysToSort.sort(SortOrder);
}
```

I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sort'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.sort()` on arrays.  You cannot `.sort()` an object as objects don't have an order to their properties and thus don't have a `.sort()` method.

If `TheDays` is an array, then it's unclear what you're trying to do with the `$.extend(false, TheDays);` line of code.  If you can explain what that is supposed to do, we can probably help with what you should be doing instead so that `TheDaysToSort` is an array that you sort.

For example, if you're trying to just make a copy of `TheDays`, then I'd suggest this line instead of the `.extend()` line:

```
var TheDaysToSort = TheDays.slice(0);  // make copy of array for sorting
```

Comment: Doesn't var TheDaysToSort = $.extend(false, TheDays); create a new array? I don't want to modify the order of the array that comes in as the parameter. Would writing var TheDaysToSort = TheDays; create a reference or a copy?

Comment: ok, very cool, I didn't know about .slice(0); now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie - NO.  `$.extend(false, TheDays);` does not produce an array.  See my edited answer for a way to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
 var TheDaysToSort = $.extend([], TheDays);
```

then `TheDaysToSort` will be correct array which will be sorted successfully.