# How sort this array of items by date in desc order (I used loadash sortBy but it returns oldest first while I need newest first)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-5

How can I sort this array of objects with dates using desc order?

I tried loadsh sortBy

```
  if ( sort && sort == "new") {
      items = _.sortBy(items, (dateObj) => {
      return new Date(dateObj.pubDate);
      });
      }
```

But it returns oldest items first while I need newest first. How can be it fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript sorting array of objects by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808063/javascript-sorting-array-of-objects-by-date)

Comment: what items? is it an array or object? can you show it?

Comment: @Kinglish I just need to modify above  function in a way that it will support desc for Lodash's sortBy

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy "This method is like _.sortBy except that it allows specifying the sort orders of the iteratees to sort by."

Comment: @ISAE how will it work for above example? Syntax is a bit confusing since in docs it uses ordering based on several properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are already using lodash, the solution is simple and involve just a minimal modification to your current code:

```
items = _.orderBy(items, (dateObj) => {
      return new Date(dateObj.pubDate);
      }, 'desc');
```

lodash [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) is very similar to `sortBy` with the addition of a third parameter, which specify the sort order (asc or desc), and the difference that the 'iteratee' could also be 'iteratees', by specifying an array of properties to sort by, in which case the sort order could also be an array with corresponding order strings for each property.